# How to add "Prince" library to CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, wamp, princexml

I want to use this library: http://www.princexml.com/ That helps me create PDF files from an HTML/XML files.

- I downloaded the PHP zip file from here: http://www.princexml.com/download/wrappers/ and added it to my "libraries" folder in the codeigniter directory. 
  from what I know, I just have to include/call the library and use it's functions regularly. 
  https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html
- I am using WAMP (Windows) so I created an Alias to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Prince\engine\bin` where the prince.exe is found, and called it "prince" (`http://localhost/prince`).

had this on my controller:

```
public function banana(){

    $this->load->library('prince');

    $prince = new Prince('http://localhost/prince/prince.exe');


    $xmlPath = 'http://localhost/temp/test.html'; 

    $this->prince->convert_file_to_passthru($xmlPath);


}
```

And I got these errors:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: Missing argument 1 for Prince::__construct(), called in
>   C:\wamp\www\tools\system\core\Loader.php on line 1247 and defined
>
> Filename: libraries/prince.php
>
> Line Number: 48
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: C:\wamp\www\tools\application\libraries\prince.php Line: 48
>   Function: _error_handler
>
> File: C:\wamp\www\tools\application\controllers\aso\Cli_kas.php Line:
>   304 Function: library
>
> File: C:\wamp\www\tools\index.php Line: 292 Function: require_once
>
> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined variable: exePath
>
> Filename: libraries/prince.php
>
> Line Number: 50
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: C:\wamp\www\tools\application\libraries\prince.php Line: 50
>   Function: _error_handler
>
> File: C:\wamp\www\tools\application\controllers\aso\Cli_kas.php Line:
>   304 Function: library
>
> File: C:\wamp\www\tools\index.php Line: 292 Function: require_once
>
> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: proc_open(): CreateProcess failed, error code - 87
>
> Filename: libraries/prince.php
>
> Line Number: 796
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: C:\wamp\www\tools\application\libraries\prince.php Line: 796
>   Function: proc_open
>
> File: C:\wamp\www\tools\application\libraries\prince.php Line: 528
>   Function: convert_internal_file_to_passthru
>
> File: C:\wamp\www\tools\application\controllers\aso\Cli_kas.php Line:
>   311 Function: convert_file_to_passthru
>
> File: C:\wamp\www\tools\index.php Line: 292 Function: require_once
>
> An uncaught Exception was encountered
>
> Type: Exception
>
> Message: Failed to execute "" --structured-log=buffered
>   "http://localhost/temp/test.html" -o -
>
> Filename: C:\wamp\www\tools\application\libraries\prince.php
>
> Line Number: 814
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: C:\wamp\www\tools\application\libraries\prince.php Line: 528
>   Function: convert_internal_file_to_passthru
>
> File: C:\wamp\www\tools\application\controllers\aso\Cli_kas.php Line:
>   311 Function: convert_file_to_passthru
>
> File: C:\wamp\www\tools\index.php Line: 292 Function: require_once

This is my first time running an external library from CodeIgniter, I am not sure what to do and codeigniter docs don't mention too much information.

Creating the ALIAS didn't work, so I think this is why it's not recognizing the variable of the `exePath`.

**How do I all the "Prince" library and get it working on CodeIgniter?**

Comment: In my experience, when you load a library, it creates an instance of  that libraries worker (i.e. new Prince()), and adds it as a member to the CI object. So after you load it like you're doing: `$this->load->library('prince');`, you can access prince functions with `$this-><prince_function>();`

Comment: no.. The first errors I get is because it's expecting a variable in the construct function within the library. and I'm not sure what to do. 
I tried adding the EXE path (using the ALIAS: `http://localhost/prince/prince.exe`) but it doesn't seem to work like that :X

Comment: Can you then verify  that this does not work when you're removing the second line where you manually instantiate the Prince class?

Comment: @Glubus yes, I get the same error :X

Comment: You might also try PrinceXML's cloud-partner: https://docraptor.com. That would remove the need for installing a library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use "Prince" as a library on CI:

1. Add the Prince.php to the library folder (/application/library/Prince.php) and make sure the file names first letter is capitalized.
2. To pass in variables to the library it has to be done using an array, and not a simple string.  `$exePath = array('exePath' => 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Prince\engine\bin\prince.exe');`

   `public function banana(){
       // it should be a local path instead of URL
       $exePath = array('exePath' => 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Prince\engine\bin\prince.exe');`

   ```
   // you can add parameter for the constructor call
   $this->load->library('prince', $exePath);
   // it also should be a local path where the folder should be writable by apache
   $xmlPath = 'C:\wamp\www\tools\files\banana\test.html';
   $pdfPath = 'C:\wamp\www\tools\files\banana\test.pdf';
   $this->prince->convert_file_to_file($xmlPath, $pdfPath);
   ```

   }
3. The construct grabs the variable as an array and not as a string like it should be! So I edited the `__construct` a little bit:

   `public function __construct($exePathArr)
   {
       // var_dump($exePathArr);
       $exePath = "banana"; // just to make sure that this var is a string :P
       // var_dump($exePath);
       $exePath = $exePathArr['exePath'];
       // var_dump($exePath);
       $this->exePath = $exePath;
       $this->styleSheets = '';
       $this->scripts = '';
       ... 
       .......
       ..........`

This is the post opened in "Prince" website: 
http://www.princexml.com/forum/topic/3318/princexml-and-codeigniter-how-to-add-the-library?p=1#16234

Hope this will help people who need this too.

I tested this both on WAMP and UBUNTU SERVER.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
public function banana(){
    // it should be a local path instead of URL
    $exe_path = 'c:\\some_folder\prince\prince.exe';
    // you can add parameter for the constructor call
    $this->load->library('prince', $exe_path);
    // it also should be a local path where the folder should be writable by apache
    $xmlPath = 'c:\\some_folder\temp\test.html';

    $this->prince->convert_file_to_passthru($xmlPath);
}
```

Comment: Not working. 
I tried both: `$exe_path = 'C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Prince/engine/bin/prince.exe';`
and `$exe_path = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Prince\engine\bin\prince.exe';` 
and this: `$xmlPath = 'C:\wamp\www\banana\index.html';`

Comment: And I have the `pronce.php` file in the library folder. 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I tried moving this to my ubuntu server and i got the same errors. 

I changed the variable from a string to `$params = array('exePath' => '/usr/bin/prince');` and I only get an error of `Array to string conversion php`